# fscanf reading multiple strings

Tags: c, scanf

So I am creating a c program that reads a query file filled with commands to execute on tables. So I used:

```
char command[100];
while(1)
{
    fscanf(query, "%s", command);
    x=strcmp(command, "select");
    //continue with checking for other commands etc.
    //if the command is stop then the loop breaks
}
```

My question is when I call fscanf the first time, I know it will save the command into the command array. But should I make the string "empty", or null as a better way to put it? I'm not sure if it's necessary when working with strcmp or in general with overwriting arrays with fscanf. Thank you!

Comment: What you should do is test the return value from fscanf; anything else is a recipe for surprises, such as non-terminating loops.

Comment: You don't need to worry about clearing out the array.  But there are several other things to worry about, with `fscanf` in general, and with `%s` in particular.  `fgets` would probably be a better choice.

Comment: Perhaps `char command[100] = { "" }; while (fscanf(query, "%99s", command) == 1) { ... }` will insure safer coding.

Comment: @Jens that would work, but I have multiple commands with the same amount of characters...numRows, rowStat, numCols, etc. but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @SteveSummit would you mind explaining that? To me (which is probably incorrect) I thought that they did close to the same thing

Comment: @John The biggest problem with `fscanf` and `%s` is that it's hard to prevent overflow of the destination buffer (in this case, `command`).  More generally, though, the scanf family of functions has tons of other problems, and trying to use them for robust input is almost always far more trouble than it's worth.  (The way the various format specifiers do or don't skip leading whitespace, and the inadequate mechanisms for intelligent error recovery in the case of unexpected input, just always seem to lead to trouble. Follow C questions here for more than about 5 minutes and you'll see plenty.)

Comment: Ahh, the glorious buffer overflow returns again!

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you so much! I'll look into it more

Comment: @John The number of characters has nothing to do with testing the return value of fscanf. You are only allowed to compare strings in `command` *if fscanf returned 1* (= the number of successful conversions; NOT characters). If it didn't, you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not worry about something that is going to be overwritten. You should only (**always**) worry about initializing it before using its *value*. Because otherwise it is undefined behavior.

More importantly, you should always check the return value of functions operating on memory. You can never count on "that would work". Because after some time you would get *Segmentation Fault* out of the blue and won't know how to fix it.

In case you don't know how:

```
int check;

check = fscanf(query, "%s", command);
if(check == EOF)
    perror("fscanf");
```